# Uploading video to Red5 Streaming server

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, red5

I need to upload videos to Red5 streaming server and retrieve videos from the server like playlists in  youtube using ffmpeg

I installed red5 streaming server
But on  running the admin.jsp it shows an error like this.." HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP"

Please provide me a suggestion for solving this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need the el-api.jar for the Tomcat version that's embedded. Look in your red5/plugins directory. If its Tomcat 7 then grab the zip [here](http://mirror.symnds.com/software/Apache/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.63/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.63.zip) extract the files and retrieve the el-api.jar from apache-tomcat-7.0.63/lib and drop it in the red5/plugins directory; restart red5 and it should work as expected.